# node.js / express / mocha testing post request issue

Tags: node.js, rest, testing, mocha.js

I built an app using node.js + expressjs and am using mocha to test my post request. My test is failing because the response from my post request is `null` but I don't know why...

My API:

```
api.post('/api/addreport', function(req, res) {
    console.log('add report hit..'); //this does not print during testing
    console.log(req.body); //this does not print during testing
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

My test:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('should');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var server = supertest.agent("https://localhost:3001");
var request = require('supertest');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

it("should post", function(done){
request(app.listen())
    .post('/api/addreport/')
    .send(data)
    .end(function(res){
        console.log('---response---');
        console.log(res); //returns null
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200); //returns status of null
        done();
   })
});
```

running `mocha ajax` results in:

```
 1)  should post:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
```

My data:

```
var data = {
    report_id: 'abc123' + Math.random(10),
    project_code: 'test_project_code',
    startDate: '2016-01-01',
    endDate: '2016-01-15',
};
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your data? Have you setup the express bodyparser?

Comment: Hi - i updated my question to include all my test dependency packages and data. And yes i am using the express bodyparser.

Comment: You're not testing anything. I'd at least invoke "done(err);" so you know that no error was returned. Sometimes supertest does not check all conditions (e.g. the 200 check) when an error occurs.

Comment: Hi - I updated my question. However, now I am getting the response from my post is `null`... not sure why since the api actually works in development/production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using supertest it doesn't require that you start your app in any port. Just add app.listen at supertest request

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('should');
var supertest = require('supertest');
var server = supertest.agent("https://localhost:3001");
var request = require('supertest');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

it("should add report", function(done){
request(app.listen()) // change here
.post('/api/addreport/')
.send(data)
.expect(200)
.end(function(err,res){
  done();
});
});
```

Comment: Hi - I updated my question. However, now I am getting the response from my post is `null`... not sure why since the api actually works in development/production mode..

Comment: Did you get any console.log in server side ? If doesn't is possible that you have a routing problem ? if you test using application like "Postman" or "curl" do you have any response from server ?

Comment: hi - yes, `curl --insecure --data '' https://localhost:3001/api/addreport` gives me a console.log output in the server side

Comment: Change the post at test to `.post('/api/addreport')` remove the common slash

Comment: Just to make sure your `app` is visible to supertest right ? I'm supposing that your api, like `var api = express()`, should be added at test, in the current code your api and your app from `var app = express()` are two different resources.

Comment: Yep, I just added var api = express(); but it's still returning the same error

Comment: I mean you need to export your `api` file using module.exports and import at test file

Comment: so close - i required `api` and now on the server side it prints out the body. BUT for some reason, it's still sending a `null` response although i specifically wrote `res.sendStatus(200)`..